# How to recover Pauli matrices properties in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, complex, arithmetic

I want to do a cross or dot product involving a vector of Pauli matrices
$ \vec\sigma=(\sigma^1, \sigma^2, \sigma^3) $; for example, $ \vec\sigma\times\vec\sigma=2\mathrm i\vec\sigma $ and $ \vec\sigma\cdot\vec\sigma=3 I_{2\times2} $.

Is there a simple way to do these operations?

Comment: Vectors like your $\sigma$ [can be mapped to quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Quaternions).  You could consider doing this and using the Quaternions package.  I'm saying this because implementing the algebraic properties of these matrices is the same as implementing quaternion calculations.  Also, we do need a fourth basis vector $I$ as evidenced by your last relationship ($\sigma_i^2 = I$).

Answer (score 12):

The Pauli vector:

```
σ = Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}]
MatrixForm /@ σ
```

[image]

One can define a *dot product of matrices* (in spaces of arbitrary dimension):

```
dot[a_, b_] := Total @ MapThread[Dot, {a, b}]
```

Then

```
dot[σ, σ] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

For the *cross product of matrices*, I literally took the cross product of vectors

```
Cross[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}] /. {Times[A_Symbol, B_Symbol] -> Dot[A, B]}
```

> {b.z - c.y, -a.z + c.x, a.y - b.x}

and redefined it as (in a 3D space)

```
cross[{a_, b_, c_}, {x_, y_, z_}] := {b.z - c.y, -a.z + c.x, a.y - b.x}
```

This gives

```
MatrixForm /@ cross[σ, σ]
```

[image]

i.e.

```
cross[σ, σ] == 2 I σ
```

> True

---

Because I particularly like the multidimensional cross product of vectors, I'd like to post a few links:

- [Multi-dimensional vector product](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204357) - an arXiv paper showing it can exist only in 3- and 7-dimensional spaces,
- [Cross Products of Vectors in Higher Dimensional Euclidean Spaces](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323537?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) - jstor,
- [Seven-dimensional cross product on Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product)
- [**Mathematica implementation of a 7D cross product**,](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129863/7-dimensional-cross-product)
- [Is the vector cross product only defined for 3D?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991/is-the-vector-cross-product-only-defined-for-3d) - a Mathematics.SE thread,
- [Cross product in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424482/cross-product-in-mathbb-rn) - another Mathematics.SE thread.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called `PauliMatrix`. Here is the product of two such matrices:

```
PauliMatrix[1].PauliMatrix[2]
```

For example:

```
PauliMatrix[1].PauliMatrix[1] == PauliMatrix[4]

True
```

or

```
PauliMatrix[1].PauliMatrix[2] == -PauliMatrix[2].PauliMatrix[1]

True
```

Comment: I think the OP wants symbolic results, rather than explicitly specifying the matrices.

Comment: The Pauli matrices are just particular case of geometric (Clifford) algebra orthonormal base elements. So you need some software of geometric algebra. Till you find better one, can look at my own implementation https://github.com/ArturasAcus/GeometricAlgebra. To mimic Pauli matrices you can use Cl[3,0] algebra (or Cl[2,0], where the role of third matrix is plays a bivector.

Comment: If you want to go the GeometricAlgebra way (as suggested in @user18792 's comment), there is a thread on this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223597/63709 and a slick Paclet based implementation of generalized Geometric Algebra https://github.com/sw1sh/GeometricAlgebra

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
pv = σ /@ Range[3];
```

Then this verifies $ \vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{\sigma}=3I $:

```
(Inner[Dot, pv, pv] /. σ -> PauliMatrix) == 3 IdentityMatrix[2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

And this verifies $ \vec{\sigma}\times\vec{\sigma}=2\mathrm i\vec{\sigma} $:

```
2 HodgeDual[Outer[f, pv, pv]] // Normal;
(% /. {f -> Dot, σ -> PauliMatrix}) == (2 I pv /. σ -> PauliMatrix)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using FeynCalc 9.3 or above (could be interesting for particle physicists)

```
CLC[i, j, k] CSI[j].CSI[k] // PauliSimplify[#, PauliReduce -> True] & // FCE
```

> ```
> 2 I CSI[i]
> ```

```
CSI[i].CSI[i] // PauliSimplify // FCE
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

`CSI` is a shortcut for a Cartesian Pauli sigma matrix, while `CLC` denotes a Cartesian Levi-Civita tensor. `PauliSimplify` handles simplifications of the Pauli algebra. The option `PauliReduce` is used to reduce every Pauli chain to at most one Pauli matrix per term. `FCE` converts the output into a notation that is easier to read (external notation).