# Assign value to an odd function

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

I defined an odd function by

```
f[0]:=0;
f[x_?Negative]:=-f[-x]
```

Now I want to define the function for certain known values

Case a)
If the known value is positive, it has no problem, i.e.:

```
f[1]:=7
```

it perfectly works because when I require f[-1] Mathematica tell me the correct answer -7;

Case b) 
If the known value is negative

```
f[-3]:=5
```

Mathematica store it but when I ask it f[3] it doesn't write -5.

I know this is because of my very definition, but it's an elegant way (possibly without helper functions and without storing manually both values at x and -x) to get the correct result?

Comment: You asked an almost identical question:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136201/skewsymmetric-function/136231#136231. The solution I provided there will work here too.

Comment: Not a complete solution: ``f[x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ] := -f[-x]``

Comment: The answer provided in this question is superior to the answer contained in the other question, and it generalises better this way. As such I vote to **leave this question open**, if this remains open I'd argue the other question should be closed as duplicate of this one.

Comment: **Note to community**: I intend to **Merge** this question with the presently marked duplicate which will move its answers to that question.  *This action is not revertible.*  If anyone objects to this plan please voice your concern ASAP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because *Mathematica* prioritizes specific function definitions over general ones, simply making the definition

```
M[i_, j_] := -M[j, i]
```

will work as long as you only try to evaluate `M` with values for `i` and `j`  for which either `M[i, j]` or `M[j, i]` have been explicitly defined. Otherwise you get infinite recursion:

```
M[1, 2] := a
M[4, 3] := b

M[1, 2]
(* a *)

M[2, 1]
(* -a *)

M[3, 4]
(* -b *)

M[1, 3]
(* $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of M[3,1]. *)
(* Hold[-M[3, 1]] *)

Clear[M]
```

To avoid this, we can make a definition for `M` that only allows itself to be recursed twice, like so:

```
Module[{n = 0},
  M[i_, j_] /; n < 2 := Block[{n = n + 1}, -M[j, i]]
]
```

The variable `n` counts the number of times that this definition of `M` has been called recursively. If `n` is less than two, the definition applies, and the `i` and `j` are swapped. When `n` is equal to two, the definition doesn't apply, and evaluation terminates. Since at this point the definition has been applied twice, the original expression is returned.

Now we have

```
M[1, 2] := a
M[4, 3] := b

M[1, 2]
(* a *)

M[2, 1]
(* -a *)

M[3, 4]
(* -b *)

M[1, 3]
(* M[1, 3] *)
```

(Side note: *Mathematica* colors the `n` in the `Block` expression red, because it thinks that we've created a naming conflict between the `Module` and the `Block`, but in fact it works just how we want.)

Comment: Edited to simplify the definition of `f[x]`.

Comment: are you willing to rewrite your answer to match the example given in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136201/skewsymmetric-function/136231#136231?  If so I think we could close this question and then *merge* it into the other, thereby moving your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure, I can do that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I edited the answer to refer to the other question. If you end up not merging, please revert it.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I intend to do that shortly but since a Merge is not reversible I'll leave at least a small window for objections.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition only inverts negative argument to positive but not the other way. And when you define `f[-3]=5` and run `f[3]`, 3 is not negative, so it will not be evaluated.

One way to solve this problem is to simply remove that pattern test, i.e. `?Negative`

Following Michael's suggestion, if you don't remove that test, adding a definition for `?Positive` also works, in case the argument becomes something strange.

Comment: You might want to test that....

Comment: @MichaelE2 I got that, thanks.