# Define antisymmetric function

Tags: function-construction

Assume I'm trying to naively define an antisymmetric function`f[x_, y_] := -f[y, x]`and assign it a value at some point `f[1, 2] = 1;`. After this, calling `{f[1, 2], f[2, 1]}` gives `{1,-1}` as desired. However, evaluating `f[1,3]` leads to an infinite recursion with result `Hold[f[1, 3]]`.

My goal is to write a definition of `f[x,y]` in such a way that it tries both variants `f[x,y]` and `-f[y,x]` to see if a value is assigned for any of them. If it is, the function should evaluate to this value. If it isn't, then it should stay unevaluated but avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: Just use a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) in your definition to avoid the infinite loop:  `f[x_, y_] /; (!OrderedQ[{x,y}]) := -f[y, x]`

Comment: In this case if I define `f[2,1]=-1` then `f[1,2]` will stay unevaluated. My whole purpose is to not care whether I should define `f[x,y]` or `f[y,x]`.

Comment: Perhaps this is what I'm looking for http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Feb/msg00383.html.  The key is inspecting `DownValues`.

Comment: What should happen if you try `f[1,1] = 1`???

Comment: Well, if you don't mind a hacky solution, you could use `f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] /; Quiet[NumericQ[f[b, a]]] := -f[b, a]`.

Comment: What is the purpose of your definition though? If you ultimately want to use this as a condition e.g. in solving equations etc, it would be best expressed as an equation, rather than a definition. Could you expand on *WHY* you need this?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I see what you mean but my context is more general then just numeric values. @MarcoB I'm doing Hamiltonian mechanics and `f[x,y]` should represent the Poisson bracket of `x` and `y`. When I introduce new degrees of freedom and define their bracket, say `f[q[i_],p[j_]]=KroneckerDelta[i,j]`, I don't want to give a separate definition for `f[p[i_],q[j_]`.

Comment: @WeatherReport I wonder if that's a good example, given that `KroneckerDelta` is symmetrical; in that specific case you could define `ClearAll[f]; f[OrderlessPatternSequence[q_[i_], p_[j_]]] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]` and then both `f[q[3], p[3]]` and `f[p[3], q[3]]` would work to return $1$ with one definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skew-symmetric function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136201/skew-symmetric-function).  Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137862/totally-antisymmetric-function

Comment: @MarcoB Nono, `f[p[3], q[3]]` should evaluate to `-1`. And there is no inconsistency with `KroneckerDelta` being symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as requested:

```
Clear@f
Module[
  {enabled = True},
  f[x_, y_] /; enabled := Block[
    {enabled = False},
    With[
      {res = f[y, x]},
      -res /; res =!= Unevaluated@f[y, x]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Testing it:

```
f[1, 2]
(* f[1, 2] *)

f[2, 1] = 2
(* 2 *)

f[1, 2]
(* -2 *)

f[2, 1]
(* 2 *)
```

#### How

There are a few things that make this work:

- The `Module`/`Condition`(`/;`)/`Block` combination ensures that the definition is not infinitely reinserted into itself (you can remove the `Module` if you don't worry about the `enabled` flag colliding with anything
- In this setting, we can safely evaluate `f[y,x]` is safe.
- The last part is the second `Condition`(`res =!= Unevaluated@…`), which only applies the "flipping" of arguments if it actually evaluates to something else

Comment: This works in my actual problem, great! The fact that `x==Unevaluated[x]` gives `True` seems counter-intuitive to me. I was thinking about how to check whether some change in expression really occurs, and this is the way to go.