# How to specify algebraic relations between objects?

Tags: algebra

so I'm wanting to screw around a bit with Geometric Algebra in Mathematica. To start, I want to create some basis objects: $e_1,~ e_2,~e_3$ and then specify the relations between them which are 
$$
e_i e_j =-e_je_i ~~~\mathrm{For}~~ i \ne j
$$
and
$$
   e_i e_j=
    \bigg{\{}
    \begin{array}{lr}
      -e_je_i,& \mathrm{For}~ i\ne j \\
      1,& \mathrm{For}~ i=j
    \end{array}
$$
Hence, I'm hoping that say the command:

```
Simplify[e1 e2 e1 e2]
```

Would return

```
-1
```

This feels like something Mathematica should be capable of doing fairly elegantly but I really don't know as I'm not a very experienced user. Could anyone shed some light on how they might approach this?

Comment: Typically, I use operations that don't have definitions associated with them (in particular, `NonCommutativeMultiply` (infix notation: `**`)), and define replacement rules or destructuring functions to simplify them. How much functionality do you need? What kind of algebra are the `e`'s a basis of?

Comment: The `e`'s are the basis vectors of 'Geometric Algebra' which is essentially a generalization of regular vector algebra and complex numbers. Essentially, if you have two vectors that are elements of the Geometric Algebra, $u$ and $v$, $uv=u \cdot v +u \wedge v$ where the dot product and wedge products there are the operations we're familiar with from regular vector algebra and exterior algebra.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that we extend this basis to the full space by allowing scalar multiplication by elements of a field (complex numbers) and addition of the vectors? So that all elements of the space are straight-up linear combinations of the `e`s? Then, you allow multiplication of the linear combinations by linearly extending multiplication of the basis vectors?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's a very nice way to work with vectors. For instance, you can do rotations of any object using $v'=e^{B\theta /2} v e^{-B\theta /2}$ where B is some bivector specifying the plane of rotation, ie it could be $B=e_1 e_2$ for a rotation in the plane spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$. For vectors lying in the plane of rotation, this simplifies even more to the form you're familiar with from complex numbers, $v'=e^{B\theta}v $

Comment: Notice that any such bivector is a square root of $-1$, ie $(e_1e_2)^2=e_1e_2e_1e_2=-e_1e_2e_2e_1=-e_1e_1=-1$ similarly for $(e_2e_3)^2=e_2e_3e_2e_3=-e_2e_3e_3e_2=-e_2e_2=-1$ etc.

Comment: As for what functionality I need out of this algebra, I'd like to just use it instead of conventional vectors for some things but I realize that might be difficult. I just want to see how much I can integrate these objects into Mathemtica without too much effort.

Comment: I can write something to get you started. I'll add more details later if I can find the time.

Comment: For some ideas on working with commutators, might check section "Some
 noncommutative
 algebraic
 manipulation" [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262223580_Symbolic_FAQ)

Comment: I started developing a package awhile back for doing GeometricAlgebra. It's incomplete, as of now, but it does some basic simplification and formatting of multivectors. Feel free to clone/contribute on github :):  https://github.com/pacojain/GeometricAlgebra

Comment: @Paco Jain You also can look at Stacey Staples package 
CliffMath2014a.m  http://www.siue.edu/~sstaple/index_files/research.htm  different approach or mine optimized reimplementation of the base elements multiplication in  https://github.com/ArturasAcus/GeometricAlgebra

Comment: I have just developed my first version of yet another package that does GA. The approach is quite different than ArturasAcus so offers some variety. It is available at github.com/matrixbud/Geometric-Algebra

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are different ways to go about doing this. I'll set `UpValues` on `e` for the multiplication of the basis vectors as you've defined them, and I'll use replacement `Rule`s for the simplification of products of vectors expanded in the basis.

First of all

```
Unprotect[e]
ClearAll@e
e /: NonCommutativeMultiply[e[i_], e[j_]] /; i < j := -NonCommutativeMultiply[e[j], e[i]]
e /: NonCommutativeMultiply[e[i_], e[i_]] := 1
Protect[e]
```

This sets up a "normal order" for the products of basis vectors. It might not be what you want, but it aids in simplifying compound expressions. Once you've run the lines above, then (non-commutative) products of the `e`s are automatically sorted according to descending order left to right:

```
e[3] ** e[3]
(* 1 *)
```

and

```
e[1] ** e[2]
(* -e[2] ** e[1] *)
```

and

```
e[2] ** e[1]
(* e[2] ** e[1] *)
```

To extend this basis to a linear space, we form all formal linear combinations of these basis elements. Particular examples are

```
ClearAll[a,b]
vec1 = Sum[e[j] a[j], {j, 1, 3}]
vec2 = Sum[e[j] b[j], {j, 1, 3}]
(* a[1] e[1] + a[2] e[2] + a[3] e[3] *)
(* b[1] e[1] + b[2] e[2] + b[3] e[3] *)
```

Then, we can implement some linearity rules and scalar rules

```
ncmRules = {
   a___ ** (-b_) ** c___ :> -a ** b ** c,
   a_Plus ** b_ :> (# ** b & /@ a),
   a_ ** b_Plus :> (a ** # & /@ b),
   x___ ** a_ ** y_ /; FreeQ[a, e] :> a x ** y,
   x_ ** a_ ** y___ /; FreeQ[a, e] :> a x ** y,
   x___ ** (a_ y_) ** z_ /; FreeQ[a, e] :> a x ** y ** z,
   (x_) ** (a_ y_) ** z___ /; FreeQ[a, e] :> a x ** y ** z,
   NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] :> a
 };
```

and define a function that applies these rules:

```
ncmSimplify[expr_] := expr //. ncmRules
```

For instance,

```
Collect[vec1 ** vec2 // ncmSimplify, _e ** _e]
(* a[1] b[1] + a[2] b[2] + a[3] b[3]
    + (a[2] b[1] - a[1] b[2]) e[2] ** e[1]
    + (a[3] b[1] - a[1] b[3]) e[3] ** e[1]
    + (a[3] b[2] - a[2] b[3]) e[3] ** e[2] *)
```

and

```
e[1] ** e[2] ** e[1] ** e[2] // ncmSimplify
(* -1 *)
```

Comment: @Mason. See if this works for you. See if you can increase the functionality by adding rules, but be careful of adding rules that lead to infinite recursion, because `ncmSimplify` is defined using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`), which scans an expression, replacing parts until it doesn't change anymore.

Comment: Wow that was fast! I'll play around with this tonight, but it looks like it's exactly what I wanted. Yes, your product between two vectors looks good. Scalars are an element of this space. I'll try and add some rules to get more functionality if I can but this is a great start, I'll keep you updated!

Comment: @Mason. I noticed an error in the definition of `ncmRules`. I missed the factor of `b` in `a b x ** y` in the third replacement rule, which would cause the expansion of `vec1 ** vec2` to not include the expansion coefficients of `vec2`. It should be fixed and working now, and I updated the example to show this.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the problem, thanks for catching that. One thing I've noticed since playing around with it over the past little while is that I can't quite figure out how to make Mathematica know that `e[1]**e[2]**e[1]**e[2]=-1` Any advice on fixing that out?

Comment: I suspect that the way to do this is to modify ncmRules such that `stuff**(-e[i] ** e[j]) -> -1*stuff ** e[i] ** e[j]`

Comment: @Mason. I always find that I have to experiment a lot to determine the right set of rules. I have updated the post with a set of rules that I *think* captures all the linearity and scalar rules correctly.

Comment: very nice! I have a lot to learn about this stuff but your examples are helping with my intuition

Comment: So I modified ncmSimplify as follows: `ncmSimplify[expr_] :=Collect[Collect[Collect[ expr //. ncmRules, _e], _e ** _e], _e ** _e ** _e]` this way I don't have to go through more steps to group like terms.

Comment: @Mason. `Collect[expr //. ncmRules, {_e,  _e ** _e,  _e ** _e ** _e}]` is more concise and should work.

Comment: Right, that makes sense

Comment: Is there an easy way to make the degree of `e` variable, so that `e[i_]^d=1`?

Answer (score 6):

There is a new [paclet](https://github.com/sw1sh/GeometricAlgebra) for doing Geometric Algebra:

```
PacletInstall["https://wolfr.am/N9OenlOc"]
<< GeometricAlgebra`;
```

You can construct multivectors of any algebra with it, and use it in computations:

```
{e1, e2, e3} = MultivectorBasis[GeometricAlgebra[3], 1];

e1 ** e2 ** e1 ** e2
(e1 ** e2) ^ 2
e1 ^ (3/5)
```

And more:

```
Inverse[2 e1]
MultivectorFunction[Exp, e1]
(e1 + 3 e2)["Normalize"]
(e1 + 2 e2 + e3)["Conjugate"]
e1["Dual"]
MultivectorMatrix[e1 + I e2]
ConvertGeometricAlgebra[e1, GeometricAlgebra[0, 3]]
```