# Writing Mathematica code for putting in commutation relations in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I am trying to write a mathematica code to accomplish the following:

For a given $n$, consider $(ab)^n$, which is a string of the form $\underbrace{ababab...ab}_{n\text{ times}}$.

I want to replace $ba$ with $ab+1$, and then expand. For instance, if $n=2$, then we get `abab->a(ab+1)b=aabb+ab`

I have been having a very hard time writing code for this. Especially, manipulating strings using Mathematica has proved to be extremely difficult.

Any ideas how I could write this code?

Comment: Have you considered using strings only for the formatting? After all, those expressions are really non-commutative products, not strings.

Comment: Sounds like an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Don't use strings. Use `NonCommutativeMultiply` and define replacement rules that do what you want.  I'll find some examples/

Comment: [Here's one example of the  kind of thing you can do.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130268/29734)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following might help, based on the expected result so far :

> *n = 2 -> aabb+ab*

> *n = 3 -> aaabbb+3aabb+ab*

```
Clear[f, g, h]
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, Listable}]
g[args___] := Fold[Distribute[f@##] &, 
  f @@ SequenceReplace[DeleteElements[List@args, {1}] , {b, a} -> f[a, b] + 1]]

h[p_] := Module[{l = Flatten@Array[{a, b} &, p]}, 
  Simplify[g @@ l //. f -> g] /. f[args__] :> StringJoin@Map[ToString, {args}]]

# -> h@# & /@ Range[6] // TableForm
```

> *1->ab*
>
> *2->aabb+ab*
>
> *3->aaabbb+3 aabb+ab*
>
> *4->aaaabbbb+6 aaabbb+7 aabb+ab*
>
> *5->aaaaabbbbb+10 aaaabbbb+25 aaabbb+15 aabb+ab*
>
> *6->aaaaaabbbbbb+15 aaaaabbbbb+65 aaaabbbb+90 aaabbb+31 aabb+ab*

Alternatively, using a more direct way (https://oeis.org/A008278)

```
h[p_] := Plus @@ Table[StirlingS2[p, k]  StringJoin@
     Flatten@Map[x |-> Array[ToString@x &, k], {a, b}], {k, p, 1, -1}]

# -> h@# & /@ Range[6] // TableForm
```

> *Same result*

Comment: For some reason Mathematica is taking forever to execute this code. Did it also take long for you to run this?

Comment: @RyanHendricks Did you try it with a fresh kernel? For a small n (n=6), `RepeatedTiming[# -> h@# & /@ Range[6]]` gives on my machine *0.0390404* for the first version (using substitution) and *0.000184193* for the second one (using `StirlingS2`).

Answer (score 3):

Define 2 functions. This one turns strings like "a^3" to "aaa":

```
replacePower[str_String]:=
StringReplace[str,c_~~"^"~~n:DigitCharacter..:>StringRepeat[c,ToExpression[n]]]
```

Test it:

```
In[]:= replacePower["a^11"]
Out[]= aaaaaaaaaaa
```

This one does the job:

```
f[n_Integer]:=
replacePower[StringReplace[ToString[Expand[ToExpression[StringReplace[
StringJoin[Table["ab",n]],"ba"->"(a*b+1)"]]],InputForm],{" "->"","*"->""}]]
```

Test it:

```
In[]:= f[2]
Out[]= ab+aabb

In[]:= f[5]
Out[]= ab+4aabb+6aaabbb+4aaaabbbb+aaaaabbbbb
```

You can apply similar methods to other cases you might have.

Comment: This alsmost does the trick, but there seem to be some errors. For example, $f[3]$ should be $aaabbb+3aabb+ab$. However, this program gives us $aaabbb+2aabb+ab$.