# Create a list of matrices

Tags: matrix, physics

I need a complete set of 2x2 matrices: first the Identity matrix and then the Pauli matrices. I need also an index (spacing from 1 to 4) to indicate a single one of those. Thank you very much

Comment: PauliMatrix does exactly this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PauliMatrix.html
remember to check the documentation before posting here. The ordering might be shuffled respect to what you want, but you can redifine new names in the order that you prefer

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129801/22013).

Answer (score 1):

```
mats = PauliMatrix[Range[0, 3]];

MatrixForm /@ mats
```

[image]

```
mats[[3]]
```

> ```
> {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much.